# MacBook map Windows keyboard Fn key

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I am using a 4TECH Windows keyboard with US English layout (picture). I want to map the Fn key to Option key. My Mac doesn't recognise that key - it simply doesn't do anything. Is there a way to fix it?

[image: keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check - 1) if there are multiple choices, that you have the correct keyboard selected in the menu at the top of the Modifier Keys panel,

[image]

and 2) that Fn itself is correctly recognised on its own if you switch on Dictation [with Fn key in the previous section set back to default]

[image]

If 1) but not 2) then your keyboard is not supported.

*Late edit*
I just tested a PC-type keyboard on one of the Macs here & discovered another ***big*** clue… if the Fn key doesn't appear at all in this list, it's a sure sign the Mac is not going to accept it even exists -

[image]

<sup>Pics from Mojave, but even though Ventura has moved everything, there should be no difference in functionality</sup>